# Trouble with using ode45 to solve a differential equation (error with the initial conditions vector?)

Tags: matlab, ode45

Hello i am trying to setup an ode45 to solve this differential equation ρaCaVdTin/dT= Qshort − Qconv,cond − Qinfilt where Qshort Qconv and Qinflit are all equations describing the loss or gain of heat in a greenhouse.

What i am trying to achieve is by giving a column vector variable of external temperature wind speed and light intensity i want the ode45 to give me the internal temperature for the corresponding value of external temperature wind speed etc ie i want Tin(1) to come from ode45 which will use the first time value from my tspan the first external temperature etc.

The way i ve coded it by inputting a breakpoint inside the function i ve noticed that from the first execution of my code the internal temperature vector is already a 297x1 column vector same length as my tspan.going past the breakpoint of dT results in an error that the initial conditions vector must have the same number of elements as the vector returned.
The question is, is there a way to achieve my intended result which is  as i ve stated above for ode45 to use one value of my vectors to get one result?
Sorry for my bad english it isn't my first language and thanks in advance.

[image: error and sizes of my vectors]

```
L=4;
W=3.7;
H=3;
volup=1*(1*4)/2; %ogkos trigwnikhs orofhs
voldown=W*L*2;  %ogkos katw or8ogwniou parellhlepipedou
V=voldown+volup; %Sunolikos ogkos
taxythtaaera = importdata('taxythta aera.txt');
exwterikh=importdata('metablhtes.txt');
ilios=importdata('hlios.txt');




S=L*W;

Vw=taxythtaaera*0.27777777777778;
Tac=15; %8ermokrasia se kelsioy
Ta=exwterikh+273.15; %se kelvin kai 15 se kelsiou kserw gw
Ta(265)=[];
Ta(143)=[];
Ta(53)=[];
Pa=1.137; %air density inside
Ca=1005;   %specific heat of air
sta=Pa*Ca*V;
ac=0.1;     %cover absorbtivity
tc=0.85;    %cover transmittance
I=ilios;    %kanonika pinakas olikh iliakh aktinobolia w/m^2
Sc=H*W; 
Tsky= 0.0552.*(Ta.^1.5);
Tskyc=Tsky-300;
R=0.75;        %air changes per hour APO FUSIKO AERISMO
Qshort=ac*tc*S*I;
stat=Qshort/sta;
stat2=S/sta;
stat3=5.2*(R/((Sc*L))^1/2);
stat4=R/V;
ho=2.8+1.2.*Vw;
ho(132)=[];
ho(53)=[];
ho(274)=[];
stat5=((ho*S)/sta)*(1-tc);
Kc=0.028;    %cover K w*m^-1*k^-1
Lc=0.03;    %cover thickness
%dT=Qshort/pa*ca*V-U*(S/Pa*Ca*V)(T-Tout)-(Pa*Ca*R/Pa*Ca*V)*(T-Ti)/3600-(ho*S*(1-tc)/(Pa*Ca*V)(T-Tsky)
t0=0;
To=286.15;
tend=35640;
n=297;  %giati allazei toso to apotelesma analoga me ta deigmata? sta 300 fainetai arketa sta8ero
tspan=linspace(t0,tend,n);
[tsol,Tsol]=ode45(@(t,T) funcODE(t,T,ho,Ta,I),tspan,To);
plot(tsol,Tsol-273.15)
x=Tsol-273.15;
```

that's my main program

and this is my function

```
function dT= funcODE(t,T,ho,Ta,I)



Tout=Ta;
ho=ho;
I=I;
L=4;
W=3.7;
H=3;
volup=1*(1*4)/2; %ogkos trigwnikhs orofhs
voldown=W*L*2;  %ogkos katw or8ogwniou parellhlepipedou
V=voldown+volup; %Sunolikos ogkos

S=L*W;
i=1;

Pa=1.137; %air density inside
Ca=1005;   %specific heat of air
sta=Pa*Ca*V;
ac=0.1;     %cover absorbtivity
tc=0.85;    %cover transmittance  
Sc=H*W; 
Tsky= 0.0552.*(Tout.^1.5);
R=0.75;        %air changes per hour APO FUSIKO AERISMO
Qshort=ac*tc*S*I;
stat=Qshort/sta;
stat2=S/sta;
stat3=5.2*(R/((Sc*L)^1/2));
stat4=R/V; 
stat5=((ho*S)/sta)*(1-tc);
Kc=0.028;    %cover K w*m^-1*k^-1
Lc=0.03;    %cover thickness
U=(1.0714+(1/ho)+(1/(1.52*(T-Tout).^1/3+stat3))).^-1;
dT=stat -(((R/(V*3600))*(T-Tout(i)))+(((ho*S*(1-tc))/sta)*(T-Tsky(i)))+(S*(T-Tout(i))*U(i)));
i=i+1;
```

Comment: `To` must have the same size as `T`, which is representing the inner states of the differential equation, which has obviously the same size as `Ta`.

Comment: To is the initial condition having the same size as T ie 297 will result in 297 different solutions one for each To.If i have everything as a single variable and not a column vector T comes out as a 297x1 column vector despite To being a single variable

Comment: It seems like you are misunderstanding something. `T` is just the argument to the function and thus an internal variable. The result will be written into `Tsol` which will have 297 rows and as many columns as simulated points in time. The initial condition `To` is the first column in this solution array.